# Finding integral points of quadric without degree 1 terms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, diophantine-equations, diophantine-geometry

I consider for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ the index set $I\subset\binom{n}{2}$ the following polynomial $p_I\in\mathcal{R}:=\mathbb{R}[x_1,...,x_n]$ with

$$p_I(x_1,...,x_n)=\sum_{\lbrace i,j\rbrace \in I}(x_i-x_j)^2-c$$

and $c>0$. This defines a quadric $Q$ of the form $x^TL_Ix-c$ for some matrix $L_I$, which is not invertible for any $I$, which contains for each $i\in\lbrace 1,...,n \rbrace$ at least one $S_i\in\binom{n}{2}$ with $S_i\in I$. We continue to work under this hypothesis. The polynomial $p_I$ is invariant under the action of $(\mathbb{R},+)$. I am looking for positive integral points on $Q$.

I know that in general, this is a hard problem, being equivalent to finding the rational points on a quadric. I was hoping, that the lack of first order terms in $x_i$ would render this more feasible, but I do not find any ressources on this. How could I approach the analysis for an existence result on integral points on this type of quadric?